# How to read a single backslash?

Tags: python, csv, file, file-not-found

I'm trying to run a csv file in python.

Here is the code I'm having trouble with:

```
with open("\Home\myname\Downloads\my_file.csv") as file_handler:
```

Not sure if this is relevant, but my name starts with an M and the file name starts with an A.

When I try to run it, this is the error message I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'\\Home\\myname\\Downloads\x07my_file.csv'
```

I tried replacing single backslashes with double, and I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'\\Home\\myname\\Downloads\\my_file.csv'
```

Can anyone show me how to get it to be read as just one slash? (I apologize if this is a simple question, I'm not too familiar with coding.)

Comment: use this `r"\Home\myname\Downloads\my_file.csv"`

Comment: These days forward slashes work with python on windows. But when the error text itself says `'\\Home\\myname\\Downloads\\my_file.csv'` isn't found, those are properly escaped backslashes and its means that your "Downloads" directory doesn't have a "my_file.csv". Is it really there and spelled the same?!

Comment: If `'\\Home\\myname\\Downloads\\my_file.csv'` doesn't work, then you have the file path wrong, or you don't have access to it.

Comment: @tdelaney yep that was the problem, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
with open(r"\Home\myname\Downloads\my_file.csv") as file_handler:
```

That `r` make python interpret the string as raw. This is pertinent because \ would otherwise be treated as a special character in python.

alternatively, seeing as you are using `\\` which would be the equivalent of a regular `\` in python, it is possible that `my_file.csv` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use a raw string where Python treats backslashes as literal characters. See more info [here](https://www.journaldev.com/23598/python-raw-string).

```py
with open(r"\Home\myname\Downloads\my_file.csv") as file_handler:
```